# How to turn off Hibernate logging?

Tags: hibernate, logging, startup, info

I am trying to set hibernate logging to Error.
In the log4j.properties, this is the entry I have:

```
#---------- Spring log -------------------------------
log4j.logger.org.springframework=error
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=error

#---------- Hibernate log ----------------------------
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
```

But the startup logs still show these messages:

```
31 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
2328 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
2328 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
2344 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
6734 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: <pkg.class> -> bbbbb
7656 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: <pkg.class> -> aaaaa
8422 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: <pkg.class> -> xxxx
```

How can I avoid logging these? Logging these seems to slow the initialization.

Comment: I highly doubt logging is what is causing slow initialization.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of time lag between each of these messages. Having them in the log isnt helping anyway. So looking for a way to not log these.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `log4j.properties` is not in control.

[Hibernate supports SLF4J](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-logging) and apparently has good documentation giving you an idea what you have to do.

I suggest you go one step further and be fully bullet-proof by setting up your application logging as per the [SLF4J documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Essentially, as seen in the picture below from the above documentation, with `Log4j` as your preferred `SLF4J` implementation in terms of dependencies you'll have to:

1. explicitly exclude from all your transitive `Apache Commons logging` (*jcl*) and `Java Logging` (*jul*) dependencies.
2. include in their place their corresponding SLF4J bridge libraries `jcl-over-slf4j` and `jul-to-slf4j` that will pipe any dependent libraries you have in the classpath to `SLF4J` and from there to your `Log4j` (and props file).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response @dimitrisli. Based on this, since I want to force hibernate to use the log4j mechanism, I added the slf4j-log4j12.jar into the class path. But hibernate still does not seem to use the log4j.properties settings. Is there something I am missing?